# python generator with different next() conditions

Tags: python, python-2.6

I nedd  a python generator to get the height of the line in a pdf file. 
To get this, I created a generator, which returns the height of the next line.

```
def height_generator(height):
    while height > 0:
        height -= 15
        yield(height)
```

This works perfect so far.

But I need different heights. For example if need a new paragraph in my file, I need to reduce the height by 20 instead of 15.

to get this, I want to define, if I want a new line or a new paragrapht, when I call my generator.

I treid something like this:

```
def height_generator(height):
    while height > 0:
        def spacer(height, a):
            if a == 1:
                height -= 15
                yield(height)
            elif a ==2:
                height -= 20
                yield(height)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining a function in a `while` loop, which just makes your code loop infinitely.

You need to `send(a)` to the generator to tell it what to do. For example

```
def height_generator(height):
    while height > 0:
        a = yield height
        if a == 1:
            height -= 15
        else:
            height -= 20

g = height_generator(100)
g.next()
print g.send(1) # 85
print g.send(2) # 65
print g.send(1) # 50
```

`yield` is not only a way that a generator produces values to its caller, but also can be used to send values to the generator. The argument passed to `send` will be the value of the expression `yield height`. For more detail, please read [PEP 255](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! 
Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this?:

```
def height_generator(height):
    while height > 0:
        a= yield height
        if a == 'nl':
            height -= 15
        elif a == 'np':
            height -= 20
```